# Загрузка и кодирование нескольких видеофайлов в одном процессе с прогресс-баром

Tags: php, видео

Здравствуйте!

Пожалуйста, подскажите решение:

Если на сайте есть функция - Добавить видеофайл, при этом:

1. Есть поле для перетаскивания видеофайла/окно загрузки.
2. Потом включается процесс загрузки файла на сервер (показывается прогресс-бар в %).
3. После полной загрузки файла включается процесс кодирования видеофайла.
4. Видео опубликовывается на странице пользователя.

Вопрос в том, пожалуйста, подскажите - Как объединить два процесса в один - загрузка на сервер и кодирование с отображением прогресс-бара в минутах.
И чтобы за 1 раз пользователь мог загрузить не более 9 файлов.

Такой вид для загрузки видеофайла:

```
<div class="es-story-video-progress-wrap video-upload-progress" style="text-align: center;" data-upload-progress>
    <div class="o-loader o-loader--sm o-loader--inline is-active"></div> <?php echo JText::_('Ваше видео загружается.'); ?>
</div>
```

Такой вид для кодирования видеофайла с включением прогресс-бара:

```
<?php if ($video->canUpload()) { ?>
<div class="es-story-video-progress-wrap video-progress" data-progress>
    <span class="es-story-video-status-text"><?php echo JText::_('Кодирование видео уже идёт...');?> <span data-video-uploader-progress-text>0%</span></span>
<div class="progress mb-5">
    <div class="bar" style="width: 0%" data-video-uploader-progress-bar></div>
</div>    
</div>
<?php } ?>
```

Также, есть подключённый php файл:

```
<?php if ($cluster) { ?>
<?php echo $this->html('html.miniheader', $cluster); ?>
<?php } ?>

<form action="<?php echo JRoute::_('index.php');?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

<div class="es-container es-videos es-video-form" data-video-process data-id="<?php echo $video->getItem()->id;?>">
    <div class="es-content">
        <div class="es-videos-content-wrapper">

            <div class="es-snackbar">
                <?php echo JText::_("Обработка видео");?>
            </div>

            <div class="es-video-progress-area t-lg-mb--sm">
                <div class="es-progress-wrap">
                    <div class="progress progress-success">
                        <div style="width: 1%" class="bar" data-video-progress-bar></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="progress-result" data-video-progress-result>0%</div>
                </div>

                <div class="t-lg-mt--xl t-text--muted"><?php echo JText::_('В настоящее время мы публикуем видео');?></div>
            </div>

            </div>

        </div>
    </div>

</form>
```

Буду благодарен за помощь.

Comment: Добавьте, пожалуйста, тег "PHP"

Comment: Наверное никак, потому что как вы собираетесь кодировать ещё не существующий на сервере фаил. Можно конечно сразу взять поток и его конвертить в нужный формат, но это довольно не тривиальная задача.

Comment: )) как-то ютуб это делает...

Comment: Naumov, подскажите, пожалуйста, как прогресс-бар включить и при загрузке видеофайла?

Прогресс-бар сейчас включается только при кодировке видеофайла. И, может быть, Вы знаете, как сделать прогресс-бар в не в %-м значении, а во временном. Поделитесь, пожалуйста.